# what is the difference between which gcc and dpkg -l | grep gcc

Tags: dpkg, gcc

based on Ubuntu 12.04 man page for `which`

> which returns the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be exe-
>          cuted in the current environment, had its arguments been given as  com-
>          mands  in a strictly POSIX-conformant shell.  It does this by searching
>          the PATH for executable files matching the names of the  arguments.  It
>          does not follow symbolic links.

I also know that if you want to make sure you have installed a program, you can type `dpkg -l | grep myprogram`.

Recently, I downloaded gcc41 and g++41 from a deb package. I installed them with the following command : `sudo dpkg -i gcc41-compat-4.1.2_i386.deb g++41-compat-4.1.2_i386.deb`.

My problem is that when I type `dpkg -l | grep gcc` I see this

```
ii  gcc                                    4:4.6.3-1ubuntu5                        GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.5                                4.5.3-12ubuntu2                         The GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.5-base                           4.5.3-12ubuntu2                         The GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc-4.6                                4.6.3-1ubuntu5                          GNU C compiler
ii  gcc-4.6-base                           4.6.3-1ubuntu5                          GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  gcc41-compat                           4.1.2                                   No description
ii  libgcc1                                1:4.6.3-1ubuntu5
```

As you can see, `gcc41-compat` is installed, but when I type `which gcc41`
there is not any result.
Based on the man page that I mentioned above, I should see something. Where is it? Or which part of my conclusion is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `which`

  > which gives location of binary installation directory. It is used as `which <pkgname>`

  So the command

  ```
  which gcc
  ```

  gives

  ```
  /usr/bin/gcc
  ```
- `dpkg -i`

  > `dpkg -i` is used for installation.It has nothing to do with finding a package directory.
- `dpkg -l`

  > `dpkg -l` is used to find if a package is installed or not.`dpkg -l <pkgname>` will give you an output with names of installed packages matching the given name.`dpkg -l` gives list of all packages.
- `write`

  > It is used to send message to other user.

  I can't tell why you used this one.
- `grep`

  > to show only the relevant part of the output.it is useful when piping commands.

---

1. If you want to find if `gcc` is installed, the best shot for you would be to use

   ```
   dpkg -l|grep gcc
   ```

   This will show all packages(installed) containing gcc in it's name,

   You could also use `dpkg -l gcc` but it gives output showing only those packages which contain only gcc.
2. If you want to check the location of the `gcc` binary that is in your `$PATH`, try

   ```
   which gcc
   ```

   Though there are few others too.